# How to support multi language to my HTML page using Angular.js/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to change the language of all my text inside my HTML page dynamically using Angular.js/JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
<label>Language</label>
<select>
   <option value="">Select langauage</option>
  <option value="1">English</option>
  <option value="2">Spanish</option>
</select>
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname">
</form>
```

Above one drop down is present to select different language. Here my requirement is suppose user selected language as `spanish` all static text present over there will change to Spanish language and if user will again select `english` the all data will re-change to English.

Automatic translation is needed - without translating all the text by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't angular-translate the thing you are looking for?

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

Here is quite the demo https://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: bro this is not an automatic solution

Comment: You are right. I missed the comments below one of the answers. But angular-translate can be used to replace the translated values, bro. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above you can also do this :

typically internationalization involves abstracting out the static strings and rendering them dynamically in the language of choice.

you can put the mappings in a JSON file and load it later according to the language choice. In the below example I have used a custom service `localeService` which injects the object according to the choice in the view.

```
app.service('localeService',['$injector',function($injector){

    return {
    getLocale : function(locale){
        return $injector.get(locale);
    }
  }
}]);
```

This service returns the objects that I have defined as `constants` in the module. the objects contain the mapping for different languages :

```
app.constant('english',{
    "greeting":"hello",
    "dropDownHeader":"Clickable Dropdown",
     "clickDesc" : "Click on the button to open the dropdown menu."
 });
app.constant('spanish',{
    "greeting":"ola",
     "dropDownHeader":"desplegable se puede hacer clic",
"clickDesc" : "Haga clic en el botón para abrir el menú desplegable."
 });
```

and finnaly I have used the object returned in the controller in the following way :

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',['localeService','$scope',function(localeService,$scope){

  $scope.lang = {};
  $scope.lang.locale = 'english';
  //$scope.template = localService.getLocale();
  $scope.$watch(function(scope){
    return scope.lang.locale;
  },function(newVal,oldVal){
        $scope.template = localeService.getLocale($scope.lang.locale);
  });
}]);
```

and here is the view :

```
<body ng-app="test" >

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<h2>{{template.dropDownHeader}}</h2>
<p>{{template.clickDesc}}</p>
<label>Language</label>
<select ng-model="lang.locale">
   <option value="">Select langauage</option>
  <option value="english">English</option>
  <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>

  <p>{{template.greeting}}</p>
 </div>
 </body>
```

[Here is the complete working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiran3807/drdrtmns/) :

Comment: he need an automatic solution for translation,he don't want to write text for  particular language

Comment: Here i need to change also all static content like `Clickable Dropdown,Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.`.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh : Yes.i need autometic solution.

Comment: You can change the static content by simply adding more strings in the objects that are injected. will modify the answer to show you how

Comment: It should be come autometic.

Comment: yes it is automatic... when you click on the relevant language option it displays the static text in that language...please check the fiddle

Comment: check you have set like this `
app.constant('english',{
   "greeting":"hello"
 });
app.constant('spanish',{
   "gr`

Comment: okay if automatic translation is what you need the manish's answer should be good enough. but from my experience internationalization involves writing down the translations of the same text in different languages . and all those translations are mapped to a single placeholder. My answer represents that approach